# Select rows where initial criteria is met whilst other criteria isn't for each row

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following SQL table:

```
ID (PK) | StartDate           | EndDate             | Trial | AccountID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 2014/08/01 00:00:00 | 2014/09/01 00:00:00 | 1     | 1
2       | 2014/09/15 00:00:00 | 2014/10/15 00:00:00 | 0     | 1
3       | 2014/09/16 00:00:00 | 2014/10/16 00:00:00 | 1     | 2
```

What I need to achieve is a list of AccountIDs that have expired trial licences (Trial = 1 & EndDate < Now) but don't have a non-trial licence associated regardless of EndDate.

In the above example ID 3 would be the only one returned as ID 1 has been superseded by ID 2.

I've tried using a number of sub queries but they seem to get excessively large and still don't meet the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select acountid
from your_table
group by accountid
having sum(trail = 0) = 0
and sum(trail = 1 and enddate < now()) > 0
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I can't believe it was that easy.